# how to use sift points with optical flow?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

i have tried the following code

what i am trying to do is that i take a search region from the image and then in that region i apply sift algorithm which would give me the feature keypoints of sift and these points are then to be plugged into the LK optical flow which would then track flow of the keypoints. the above code however is still taking corner points instead of sift

```
def SIFT(sa_box, template):
    template_gray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imwrite('template.jpg', template)
    keypoints_1, descriptors_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(sa_box, None)
    keypoints_2, descriptors_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(template_gray, None)
    matches = bf.match(descriptors_1, descriptors_2)
    matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)

    good_matches = matches

    src_pts = np.float32([keypoints_1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good_matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([keypoints_2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good_matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(dst_pts, src_pts, cv2.RANSAC, ransac_thres)
    im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(src_pts, M, (dst_pts.shape[1], dst_pts.shape[0]))

    image_pts_lst = np.empty((0, 2), dtype=np.uint8)
    mask_flat = mask.flatten()
    for i, val in enumerate(src_pts):
        src_pts_mask = mask_flat[i]
        if src_pts_mask == 1:
            image_pts_lst = np.append(image_pts_lst, val, axis=0)

    pts_avg = np.mean(image_pts_lst, axis=0)
    return pts_avg[0], pts_avg[1]

while True:

    # start time to calculate FPS
    start = time.time()

    suc, frame = cap.read()
    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = frame.copy()
    if frame_idx==0:

        image = frame
        clone = image.copy()
        cv2.namedWindow("image")
        cv2.setMouseCallback("image", shape_selection)

        # keep looping until the 'q' key is pressed
        while True:
            # display the image and wait for a keypress
            cv2.imshow("image", image)
            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

            # if the 'c' key is pressed, break from the loop
            if key == ord("c"):
                break

        if len(ref_point) == 2:
            template  = clone[ref_point[0][1]:ref_point[1][1], ref_point[0][0]:
                                                              ref_point[1][0]]
            print(ref_point[0][1], ref_point[1][1], ref_point[0][0], ref_point[1][0])
            cv2.imshow("crop_img", template)
            # templates.append(template)
        # print(templates[0])
        coord=[ref_point[0][0],ref_point[0][1],ref_point[1][0],ref_point[0][0]]
        sa_box,points=search_area_cropping(clone, coord)
        top_u,bottom_u,left_u,right_u=points
        cv2.imshow('sa_box', sa_box)
        # sift_x, sift_y = SIFT(sa_box, template)
        # sift_x_u = sift_x+left_u
        # sift_y_u = sift_y+top_u
        # p0=[sift_x_u,sift_y_u]
        # p0=np.array(p0)
        # # p0 = cv2.KeyPoint_convert(p0)
        # # p0 = np.expand_dims(p0, axis=1)

        # print('sift u points ',sift_x_u,sift_y_u)
        # print('sift func points ', sift_x, sift_y)
        # if math.isnan(sift_x_u) or math.isnan(sift_y_u):
        #     sift_fail = True
        #     sift_x_u, sift_y_u = 0, 0
        # cv2.circle(img, (int(sift_x_u), int(sift_y_u)), 15, (255, 0, 255), -1)
        # cv2.imshow('sift point', img)
    # if frame_idx>0:
    #     sift_x,sift_y=SIFT(sa_box, template)
    #     sift_x_u = sift_x + left_u
    #     sift_y_u = sift_y + top_u
    #     print(sift_y_u)
    #     if math.isnan(sift_x_u) or math.isnan(sift_y_u):
    #         sift_fail = True
    #         sift_x_u, sift_y_u = 0, 0
    #     cv2.circle(img, (int(sift_x_u), int(sift_y_u)), 15, (255, 0, 255), -1)



    # Calculate optical flow for a sparse feature set using the iterative Lucas-Kanade Method
    if len(trajectories) > 0:
        img0, img1 = prev_gray, frame_gray
        # p0 = np.float32([trajectory[-1] for trajectory in trajectories]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        # p1, _st, _err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(img0, img1, p0, None,flags=cv2.MOTION_AFFINE, **lk_params)
        sift_x, sift_y = SIFT(sa_box, template)
        sift_x_u = sift_x + left_u
        sift_y_u = sift_y + top_u
        # points = [sift_x_u, sift_y_u]
        # points = np.array(points)
        points=np.zeros((1,1,2))
        points[0,0,0]=np.float32(sift_x_u)
        points[0, 0, 1] = np.float32(sift_y_u)
        points = points.astype(np.float32)
        # p0 = cv2.KeyPoint_convert(p0)
        # p0 = np.expand_dims(p0, axis=1)
        p0r, _st, _err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(img1, img0, points, None,flags=cv2.MOTION_AFFINE, **lk_params)
        # d = abs(p0 - p0r).reshape(-1, 2).max(-1)
        # good = d < 1
        #
        # new_trajectories = []
        #
        # Get all the trajectories
        # for trajectory, (x, y), good_flag in zip(trajectories, p1.reshape(-1, 2), good):
        #     if not good_flag:
        #         continue
        #     trajectory.append((x, y))
        #     if len(trajectory) > trajectory_len:
        #         del trajectory[0]
        #     new_trajectories.append(trajectory)
            # Newest detected point
            # cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), 2, (0, 0, 255), -1)

        # trajectories = new_trajectories

        # Draw all the trajectories
        cv2.polylines(img, [np.int32(trajectory) for trajectory in trajectories], False, (0, 255, 0))
        cv2.putText(img, 'track count: %d' % len(trajectories), (20, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Update interval - When to update and detect new features
    if frame_idx % detect_interval == 0:
        mask = np.zeros_like(frame_gray)
        mask[:] = 255

        # Lastest point in latest trajectory
        for x, y in [np.int32(trajectory[-1]) for trajectory in trajectories]:
            cv2.circle(mask, (x, y), 5, 0, -1)
            # cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)

        # Detect the good features to track
        p = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(frame_gray, mask=mask, **feature_params)
        if p is not None:
            # If good features can be tracked - add that to the trajectories
            for x, y in np.float32(p).reshape(-1, 2):
                trajectories.append([(x, y)])
                cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)

    frame_idx += 1
    prev_gray = frame_gray
```

Comment: "*... a search region from the image*", which image? please provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: it can be any like for example i am using a video of a car moving from one point to another ... in the first frame the user can draw rectangle on the image which then crops the image and double of the region is then called search region